# build failed while ant fresh install

Tags: dspace

```
root@biruk-Satellite-L655:/build/dspace-4.2-src-release# cd dspace/target/dspace-4.2-build
root@biruk-Satellite-L655:/build/dspace-4.2-src-release/dspace/target/dspace-4.2-build# sudo ant fresh_install
Buildfile: /build/dspace-4.2-src-release/dspace/target/dspace-4.2-build/build.xml

init_installation:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/config
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/lib
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/etc
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/webapps
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/exports
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/exports/download
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/assetstore
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/handle-server
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/search
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/log
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/upload
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/reports
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/solr
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/var
    [mkdir] Created dir: /dspace/var/oai

init_configs:
     [copy] Copying 121 files to /dspace/config
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /dspace/config

test_database:
     [java] 2017-04-30 10:12:42,728 INFO  org.dspace.core.ConfigurationManager @ Loading system provided config property (-Ddspace.configuration): config/dspace.cfg
     [java] 2017-04-30 10:12:42,738 INFO  org.dspace.core.ConfigurationManager @ Using default log4j provided log configuration.  If unintended, check your dspace.cfg for (log.init.config)
     [java] 
     [java] Attempting to connect to database: 
     [java]  - URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dspace
     [java]  - Driver: org.postgresql.Driver
     [java]  - Username: dspace
     [java]  - Password: dspace
     [java]  - Schema: 
     [java] 
     [java] Testing connection...
     [java] 
     [java] Error: 
     [java]  - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dspace"
     [java] 
     [java] Please see the DSpace documentation for assistance.
     [java]
```

here is where i got error  it happen while  installing in both window and ubuntu  how can i overcome with this error
    BUILD FAILED
    /build/dspace-4.2-src-release/dspace/target/dspace-4.2-build/build.xml:786: Java returned: 1

```
Total time: 4 seconds
root@biruk-Satellite-L655:/build/dspace-4.2-src-release/dspace/target/dspace-4.2-build#
```

# can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0):

As it says right here in the error message:

```
 Error: 
 [java]  - org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "dspace"
```

Your database connection settings aren't right. You need to either

- set up your PostgreSQL server (running on localhost) to allow connections to the `dspace` database from username `dspace`, password `dspace`; or
- change the database settings in your dspace.cfg to match what is actually needed (which depends on your local set-up).